# Sysinternals - Streams access is denied error

Tags: windows-7, sysinternals

I am using streams.exe to remove blocking of game by Windows but it is showing me "Access is denied" error although I am running the command with administrator.

Article (that one I am following) : http://darrenmyher.wordpress.com/2007/03/22/how-to-permanently-unblock-files-that-came-from-the-internet-sysinternals-streams-utility-zones-vista-and-blocked-files-in-ie/

Comment: What operating system (be as specific as possible) and how are you running the command with administrator (be as specific as possible).

Comment: Windows 7. I had put streams.exe in system32 and then moving to the folder which I had to unblock through cd command, I ran the following command: `streams -s -d *.*`

Comment: How did you run the command? Be as specific as possible. (Did you use an elevated command prompt? How did you elevate it?)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted do the same: **mass-deletion of** "Zone.Identifier" **alternate data streams (ads)** that were attached to 95 downloaded PDF files.

The manual way in windows explorer works only file by file by using the Unblock button in Properties dialog, and so would mean 95 times mouse clickery. Not very feasible, so I tried several utilities …

**What did not work:**

- "streams.exe" by SysInternals.com shows "*Access is denied*". Running it in an elevated cmd.exe did not help, either.
- "ADS Spy 1.11"by bleepingcomputer.com shows "*The following ADS streams could not be deleted. They may by locked by another program*".
- "ADS Scanner 2.01" by pointstone.com shows "*stream could not be deleted*".

I couldn't find any locks. Even quitting the explorer process and then trying again did not help.

**What DID work:**

- "UVK - Ultra Virus Killer" by carifred.com: the included "Alternate Streams Manager" was able to delete all 95 Zone.Identifier ADSes in one go.

I've no idea why the other tools failed (*and I'd still like to know!*), but at least this is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem with **streams** and tried all security options of taking ownership etc. Checking at folder level I couldn't see any difference in folders where ADS were removed and folders where access was denied. Finally, I checked at file level to see the difference between files and rather obviously **the files where access was denied were READ ONLY**. So I reset the attributes and streams worked fine.
(But, my system is still XP).