# Explorer copy hangs before all files copied (XP)

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, ntfs, alternate-data-stream

OK, so I should have moved to W10, but I still have a lot of old apps. I'm using Avast (anti virus) and Windows defender (malware only) and my harddrive is NTFS.

Recently (2017 Dec 24) windows explorer started hanging when I tried to take a backup to (NTFS) memory stick. I tried everything I could think of with permissions, restore to earlier checkpoint (wouldn't do it), reseat all the connections, clean the CPU fan, and ran System File Checker. Nothing worked.

I saw that I could read files OK, and write them to DVD. I could also copy them back from DVD to hard drive, and having copied them back I could then copy the copies to memory stick. Since copying to DVD doesn't carry all the file attributes acrosss, I took a wild guess and looked for and deleted alternate data streams on the hard drive and all is now magically OK.

**Does anyone know what is going on here, especially as the ADS have accumualed gradually over years and didn't suddenly materialise on problem day ?**

P.S. I did post an answer to a problem with the **streams** command in the course of this adventure 
[Sysinternals - Streams access is denied error](https://superuser.com/questions/781585/sysinternals-streams-access-is-denied-error/1280120#1280120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How close are you to filling the maximum size of the USB stick?  It could be the information in the ADS is filling up your space and not allowing enough room for the rest of the 'regular' files.  Remember, more than just text can be placed in the subsequent streams of a file.  Large files can be embedded into small files or folders, and just because Windows doesn't show the space, doesn't mean it's not there.  That would be my first guess.

Even if its not a space issue, it sounds like ADS is the culprit.  You are correct, the process of writing to a DVD will usually strip out ADS with only the primary stream being written.